# Merge two images in php using resource id

Tags: php

Merge two image using there Resource id.
The data about image fetched is its Resource 
image 1 : Resourceid#6
image 2: Resourceid#14
How can i merge these image.
So far,I tried :

```
imagecopymerge($im1,$im2,, 0, 0, 0, 0, 500, 100, 90)
header('Content-Type: image/png');  
imagepng($im1);
```

But this displays only one image.The image are generated correctly if produced single.How to merge these two?

Example: 
Add these two

[image]

and

[image]

so the result is:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing is that you merge one image OVER the other one. You take a part with width 500 and height 100 from the source picture and copy it over the destination starting at position 0,0. If the destionation picture has this size to, you will only see one picture.

With this method you cannot merge the pictures side by side, only one over the other.

Comment: I need to merge one over other